# TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_train'

Tags: python, validation, scikit-learn, cross-validation, gridsearchcv

I'm having trouble to use GridSearchCV with my custom estimator. I got a warning that said scoring is failed and my predict() missing 1 positional argument which is y_train.
Here is my code
`class FLVQ(BaseEstimator):

```
def __init__ (self, a=5):
        self.a = a

def fit(self, x_train, y_train):
    #somecodehere
    return self


def compare(self, x):
    distance = self.count_dist(x)
    index_dist = np.argmin(distance, axis=1)
    return np.array([self.centroid[i] for i in index_dist])

def predict(self, x_train, y_train):
    return np.sum(self.compare(x_train)==y_train.flatten())/x_train.shape[0]
`
```

and when i run my GS:

```
params={'a':[3,5]},
gs = GridSearchCV(FLVQ(), param_grid=params,cv=4, scoring="accuracy")   
gs.fit(x_train,y_train)
gs.predict(x_test)
```

i got "UserWarning: Scoring failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan." and the TypeError because my predict missing 1 argument. How do i solve this? Since i'm using predict to compare between the result and the actual label so it shows the accuracy of the model

Comment: You have defined in your function that in predict part needs to get `y_train`? why? Since if you take a look at prepared API such as `scikit-learn` for predicting you need just `x_train` or `x_test`. Are you sure that you are on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, I did not catch the point of writing `y_train` in the prediction function but just to show what I am thinking about, take a look at below:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
LR = LinearRegression()

data = np.arange(0,100)
x_train, y_train= np.split(data.sample(frac=1,random_state=1500),[int(0.7 * len(data))])
LR.fit(X_train,y_train)
LR.predict(x_train)
```

To get more info, [Scikit-learn/linear regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)